# Gazebo can't find rendering system

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone ! I have installed  the linux OS Ubuntu 12.04 and gazebo-1.0.1 on my laptop. Although the installation of Ubuntu 12.04 is successful, I ran into some issues while running gazebo. I hope that you guys can give me some advices on how to resolve them.

I have already installed the debian package of gazebo 1.0.1 using the software centre and set the environment variables as described in the online instructions. However, when i tried to run " gzserver" in the terminal. it returned the following error

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Error [RenderEngine.cc:356] Unable to load Ogre Plugin[/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/Plugin_CgProgramManager.so]...Skipping

After that I added OGRE PPA, but it didn't help. I then downloaded and installed latest version of OGRE and run "gzserver" again, but it gave me another set of  errors,

Exception [RenderEngine.cc:468] unable to find rendering system

Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find rendering system
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:468] unable to find rendering system

Exception [Sensors.cc:39] Unable to load the rendering engine

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)

Could anyone here help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41908/gazebo-can%27t-find-rendering-system/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i think your gazebo is not completely integrated with ogre...you have to install gazebo with [source pkg](http://gazebosim.org/downloads.html) as in debian package it does not completely integrates with ogre...other things u can do is that to check whether u have [setup environment variables](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/install) correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) with karma: 234 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-08-21**:
Thanks Kumar. I understand that you solved the problem by reinstalling using source pkg. May I know did you encounter problems while doing Cmake? I encountered build error ( e.g.missing: tinyxml) while doing Cmake. I followed the steps in the Readme text.

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-08-21**:
have u installed the requirements for gazebo???http://gazebosim.org/wiki/requirements

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-08-21**:
Ah! I think not. That should be it. Thanks a lot !  I will try installing again. Have a nice day!